# Implementing peer-to-peer payments with Flutter and Paypal

Tags: flutter, paypal, payment-gateway, p2p

I'm trying to implement an app that requires sending money between users.

I would like users to be able to send money through their PayPal account.

However, I cannot find any material that explains how this can be done with Flutter.

Many guides detail how to send payments to a certain source but not how payments between users can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

With [PayPal Checkout](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), be it with the web JS SDK, native SDK for iOS/Android, or v2/checkout/orders REST API alone, payments can be directed to a different destination account by including a [`payee` object](https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/#definition-payee) in the purchase_units of the request.

Example:

```
    {
      intent: 'CAPTURE',
      purchase_units: [{
        amount: {
          currency_code: 'USD',
          value: '220.00'
        },
        payee: {
          email_address: 'receiveraccount@emaildomain.com'
        }
      }]
    }
```

Comment: Basically this comes down to figuring out how to send requests in Flutter. Thank you very much!

Comment: You can call platform-specific native checkout SDKs from Flutter, https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels